# Plotting arrays with different dimensions (Matlab to Python)

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, plot

I'm trying to set this plot from Matlab to Python. I have little knowledge in Matlab and I have found almost nothing related to this.

```
plot([min(ARRAY1) ARRAY2], [ARRAY3 ARRAY3])
```

I just can't figure out what kind of plot it should create, so I can't write this on Python. The values are shown below.

```
#Python
ARRAY1.min() = 24.0
ARRAY2 = array([  20.,   85.,  115.])
ARRAY3 = array([ 20.,  50.,  50.])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provide does not run in Matlab because you are trying to plot two vectors of different size. The first vector, what would be the x-values, is `[min(ARRAY1) ARRAY2] == [24 20 85 115]`, while the second vector (y-values) is `[ARRAY3 ARRAY3] == [ 20 50 50 20  50  50]`.

However, if contrary to its name, `ARRAY1` is a square matrix with 3 columns, then `min(ARRAY1)` would provide a three-element vector with the minimum of each column of the matrix and you could then plot the values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll check the Matlab code to be sure about it.